# TASM Math coprocessor FSUB not substracting

Tags: assembly, tasm, x87

I encounter difficulties using the math coprocessor. I need to calculate the area of a triangle using Heron's formula (S=sqrt(p(p-a)(p-b)(p-c)), where p is the semiperimeter and a, b and c are the triangle's sides). I successfully read a, b, c and calculate p but I have problems in substracting a, b and c from p.
My code:

```
DATA SEGMENT PARA PUBLIC 'DATA'
A DD 0
B DD 0
C DD 0
P DD 0
PA DD 0 ; P-A
PB DD 0 ;P-B
PC DD 0 ;P-C
AREA DD 0
TWO DD 2
AUX DD 0
DATA ENDS

READ MACRO X, AUX ; THE READING MACRO FOR A, B AND C. THIS GOES FINE
LOCAL R, FINAL
PUSH EAX
PUSH EBX
PUSH EDX
MOV X, 0
MOV EBX, 10
R:
   MOV AH, 1H
   INT 21H
   CMP AL, 0DH
   JE FINAL
   CMP AL,30H
   JB R
   CMP AL, 39H
   JA R
   SUB AL, 48
   XOR AH,AH
   MOV AUX,EAX
   MOV EAX, X
   MUL EBX
   ADD EAX, AUX
   MOV X, EAX
   JMP R

FINAL:

POP EDX
POP EBX
POP EAX
ENDM

CODE SEGMENT PARA PUBLIC 'CODE'
.386
START PROC FAR
ASSUME CS:CODE, DS:DATA
PUSH DS
XOR AX,AX
PUSH AX
MOV AX,DATA
MOV DS,AX

READ A, AUX
READ B, AUX
READ C, AUX

FINIT
FLD A
FADD B
FADD C
FDIV TWO
FSTP P ;P IS COMPUTED
FLD P
FSUB A ; HERE IS MY PROBLEM. IT SEEMS IT DOESN'T SUBTRACT A
FSTP PA
FLD P
FSUB B ; ALSO, THE SAME PROBLEM HERE
FSTP PB
FLD P
FSUB C ;ALSO, THE SAME PROBLEM HERE
FSTP PC
FLD P
FMUL PA
FMUL PB
FMUL PC
FSQRT
FSTP AREA
FWAIT

RET
START ENDP
CODE ENDS
END START
```

Comment: `FSUB` works with floating point numbers. Maybe you want `FISUB` if you have an integer. Also make sure you use the proper operand sizes. Furthermore, comment your code especially if you want others to help. And, as always, learn to use a debugger and the instruction set reference.

Comment: @Jester yes, apparently it works with `FISUB`, but why? I entered 3,4,5 and gave me the area 6, fair enough. But I also entered 3,4,6 and it gave me 5.3326, so it also worked with floating point numbers.

Comment: Almost none of your floating point instructions are correct. They interpret the memory operands as 32-bit single precision floating-point numbers instead of the 32-bit integers you're provided.